# Extract a substring and x characters from a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string :

```
desc = 'Communication is a cornerstone of society. It is the expression of people who want to feel connected and share their thoughts, interests and feelings with one another. And telecommunication allows us to interact even when we are in different places and separated by a distance.'
```

If a specific substring is in desc i want to extract that substring and also the next x characters after it.

Ex :

```
if 'telecommunication' in desc :
     specific_desc = 'telecommunication allows us to interact'

if 'society' in desc:
     specific_desc = 'society. It is the expression of people who want to feel connected and 
                      share their thoughts'
```

I don't know how to  get the x characters after the specific substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the index() or find() to get the starting position of the substring, and then slicing to get the characters you want.

```
def get_sub_x(full, sub, x):
   try:
      index = full.index(sub)
      return full[index: index + len(sub) + x]
   except ValueError:
      return None

print(get_sub_x('Hello World', 'Wo', 2))
```

Outputs `Worl`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, You can use index slicing.

```
string = 'Communication is a cornerstone of society'

substring = 'Communication'

x = 15

if substring in string:
    index = string.find(substring)
    print(string[index:index + x])
```

Comment: OP says he wants the substring + the next X characters.  Just need to add in the length for the original substring in your slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
n = 15
keyword = "society"

found = re.search(f"({keyword}.*)", desc).group(0)
found = found[len(keyword) + n]
print(found)

# 'society. It is the expression of people who want to feel connected and share their thoughts, interests and feelings with one another. And telecommunication allows us to interact even when we are in different places and separated by a distance.'
```

Comment: This solution will always get the text from the specific substring to the end ,which is not what i want.

Comment: You can substring the found text

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_index (string):
    if string in desc:
        return desc.index (string)

start = get_index ('telecommunications ')
end = get_index ('even')
print (desc [start:end])
```